# How can i setup my OpenThread device running MQTT-SN clients examples to connect to AWS IoT Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot, nrf52, openthread

I am currently building a open thread based application using nRF5 SDK for Thread and nRF52840 development kits. I have chosen MQTT-SN as my application level protocol to communicate with cloud.

All my thread devices are sending data to Eclipse Paho MQTT-SN gateway. This thread devices doesn't have there own Root CA certificate nor private keys etc as there are no such macro definitions provided in Nordic SDK for Thread. So how can this thread devices communicate with the AWS MQTT broker without authentication certificates.

I know i have to enable Authentication in paho mqttsn gateway config file and provide root CA certificates, private keys in configuration file. And if i enable authentication, my thread devices wont be able to communicate with MQTTSN gateway. There is something called client list but i don't actually know whats the use of it if i have to add my new device name all time in that client list.

So can anyone please guide me how could i transmit data from my thread devices acting as MQTT-SN clients to AWS broker via MQTT-SN Gateway. Or any way around that i am unable to see.

Thanks in advance.